# How to sort localStorage by key

Tags: javascript, sorting

For some reason localStorage don't sort by the order you add data to it.

I have stored JS date milliseconds as keys in localStorage.
How can i output the key and the value from localStorage sorted by key asc?

Do i need to create another VAR from localStorage and then sort the VAR?

Comment: If you need order, then do not use a dictionary / map, instead maybe use an array of tuples, but then you no longer have key-based access.

Comment: JavaScript doesn't have tuples @luk2302. LocalStorage is key-value map store that is unordered.

Comment: Map to a desired spot in LocalStorage e.g. "test1"; make its contents an stringified array, and when you access the storage put it to a local variable and when you modify it re-save over-top of the old value.

Comment: LocalStorage keys can have values within them that are in fact sorted but not in their mapped form not naturally or without help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about saving the times as a single object using JSON.stringify(yourObject)

Something like

```
const jsTimes = localStorage.getItem("times");
const times = jsTimes ? JSON.parse(jsTimes) : {};
...
times[new Date().getTime()] = "Now is the time";
localStorage.setItem("times",JSON.stringify(times));
```

Alternatively if you must

```
const times = Object.keys(localStorage)
  .filter(key => key.length === 13 && !isNaN(new Date(key))
  .map(key => key)
  .sort() // alphabetic sort is ok on a timestamp
  .map(key => ({[key]: localStorage[key] }));
```

Comment: If they're inserting it via time-stamps their entry is sorted, how they're storing this however is incorrect.

Comment: They should allocate a TimeSlot key in the localstorage and add to that, make the modifications any-time more is added. Keep client copy saved so you timelessly keep it up to date. Overloading storage keys is bad programming.

Comment: @blanknamefornow I agree. Hence my first statement